# Storing a certificate file in SQL server table

Tags: .net, sql-server, digital-certificate

Where can I find information on storing a certificate ".cer" and "pfx" in a SQL Server table?

Can I just store it as a string or does this need to be saved as binary data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just store as `varbinary(max)` (You can store anything in that upto 2GB-1 bytes)

Edit: to qualify the slight flippancy, the fact it is a certificate is irrelevant to SQL Server like it won't recognise a Word document or PDF as such: it's all binary data

Comment: Knowing what the certificate *is* allows better manage the database and not use varbinary(max) where not needed.

Answer (score 2):

PFX is binary format. "Canonical" CER file should be a binary format too (DER-encoded binary data), though some applications put base64-encoded certs or even PEM-wrapped certs there.

Given that they are binary, you can store them either in BLOB or base64-encode them and then store them as string. But the latter doesn't make sense as base64-encoded data will consume more place in the table.